# Efficiently remove elements from a list in python which are also in given lists

Tags: python, list

So I have two lists and one main list. The elements in the main list should be removed if they are present in either of the other two lists.

Example:

```py
s1 = [1,2,3,4,7]
s2 = [3,4,5,6,20]
mainlist = [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

So, as the mainList contains the elements 6 and 7 which are also present in either s1 or s2, they should be removed and the result should be like the following.

```
resultList = [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
```

My code:

```py
for j in mainlist[:]:
    if j in s1 or j in s2:
        mainlist.remove(j)
```

Is there anyway without using the for loop? I need an efficient way to reduce time complexity. Thank you !

Comment: You can use a list comprehension, but the time complexity remains as this is an inherent property of the problem.

Comment: Thank you everyone ,i have tried every solution but its still giving me Time limit exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension, it's ready good for that kind of problem :

```
result = [x for x in mainlist if x not in s1 and x not in s2]
```

Using `list/set` manipulation you can do one of the following

```
result = list(set(mainlist) - (set(s1) | set(s2)))  # remove the concat of s1&s2
result = list(set(mainlist) - set(s1) - set(s2))    # remove s1 and s2
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can create another list by using list comprehension

```
res = [i for i in test_list if i not in s1 and i not in s2]
```

or using `filter() + lambda`

```
res = filter(lambda i: i not in s1 and i not in s2, mainlist)
```

or using `for` loop

```
for elem in mainlist:
   if elem in s1 or elem in s2:
      mainlist.remove(elem)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone ,i have tried every solution but its still giving me Time limit exceeded.

Comment: what is the time frame you have to complete this task @SuhailPappu ?

Comment: I dont know its an online contest

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mainlist = list(set(mainlist) - (set(s1)|set(s2)))
```

Here I am assuming that none of the lists have repeated elements.

You can time and compare it from other methods.

```
time_idx = time()
result = [x for x in mainlist if x not in s1 and x not in s2]
print(time() - time_idx)
```

> `0.00012612342834472656`

```
time_idx = time()
mainlist = list(set(mainlist) - (set(s1)|set(s2)))
print(time() - time_idx)
```

> `0.00010609626770019531`

The improvement is significant since this is a small list.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `s1` and `s2` to `dict`

```py
s1 = {i:i for i in s1}
s2 = {i:i for i in s2}
mainlist = [i for i in mainlist if i not in s1 or i not in s2]
```

You would lose some time with converting lists to dict, but since python dictionary is basically hash table, then search complexity is `O(1)` and not `O(n)` like with lists.
 So in the end it would be not `O(n^2)`, but `O(n)` or something like that.
 Let me know if you try this.

Comment: @SuhailPappu did you try it without list slice?

Comment: @SuhailPappu can you please edit your question with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Just use set operation to filter out

```
>>> list(set(mainlist) - set(s1+s2))
>>> [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use counter to perform this:

```
from collections import Counter

print(list(Counter(mainlist) - Counter(s1) - Counter(s2)))
Out[309]: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```